# How can I clean up this LINQ Query (SelectMany)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How can I clean up this LINQ Query to use SelectMany in the sql syntax, instead of method chaining at the end like I have done?

```
 var runPeakWidths =
     (from ipa in runAnalysis.PassAnalyses
      let peakWidths = BuildPeakWidths(ipa)
      select peakWidths)
      .SelectMany(data => data);
```

Edit:
Turned into a tight little method:

```
    public void CreateRunStatistics(Func<IPassAnalysis, IEnumerable<double>> buildMethod, string name)
    {
        var data = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.SelectMany(buildMethod);
        statistics.Add(StatisticsBase.Calc(name, data));
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me IPA is India Pale Ale...please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var runPeakWidths = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.SelectMany(ipa => BuildPeakWidths(ipa));
```

You can also use this if you prefer:

```
var runPeakWidths = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.SelectMany<Ipa, Pw>(BuildPeakWidths);
```

where `Ipa` is `ipa`'s type
and `Pw` is `PeakWidth`'s type.

I have been reliably informed (haven't verified myself) that return-type inference for method groups has now been implemented in the compiler, so this should work in C# 4:

```
var runPeakWidths = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.SelectMany(BuildPeakWidths);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `SelectMany` call can be avoided by nesting `from` clause in the query:

```
 var runPeakWidths =
      from ipa in runAnalysis.PassAnalyses
      from peakWidth in BuildPeakWidths(ipa)
      select peakWidth
```